# can i pass a state value with the jsx code ?? in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Hello everybody I'm wondering if I can pass a state value from a component to other where I'm returning jsx code to be displayed for example I have 3 components.

1

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Conteneur from './Conteneur';

class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { value: '' };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                <Conteneur values={this.state.value} />
            </form>

        );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

2 app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import Conteneur from './Conteneur';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" >
        <br />
        <Header />
        <br />
        <Conteneur />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

3 and finally

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const Conteneur = () => {


    return (

        <div className="tab"><span>ok test </span></div>

    );

};
  export default Conteneur;
```

[image: description]

I like to pass the state value of header that I have from the input to conteneur and then display in the box while I have some code all the examples that I saw online they are sending state like this:

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
...
...
  render(){
    return(
    <Sidebar data={this.state.data1}/>
    );
  }
}
```

So can I do like this `<Conteneur values={this.state.value} />` in the form ?
And I imported Conteneur.

i updated the code but the output is [image: enter image description this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do, only one thing you are missing. Receive the props in the function parameters then render that in the ui.

Like this:

```
const Conteneur = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="tab"><span>value: {props.value} </span></div>
    );
};
```

Comment: because you are rendering `<Conteneur />` twice one inside header component and one inside App component. Remove from app component it will work.